# Electronic Speed Control (ESC) basics

Tags: ros, driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to ROS and I am making an autonomous buggy scale 1:10.

I am trying to understand how to communicate with the Electronic Speed Controller (ESC) of the Buggy's DC motor. I have also checked the page: http://wiki.ros.org/Motor%20Controller%20Drivers#ROS_Motor_Controller_Drivers. And my ESC is HW-WP-1040-BRUSHED, you can see it here: https://www.redcatracing.com/products/hw-wp-1040-brushed?variant=30993631281242

I am using a Raspberry 3B+ with Ubuntu 16 and ROS Kinetic. I have already achieved the connection with the steering servo using an Adafruit servo board.

Any source I can read from is welcome.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357497/electronic-speed-control-(esc)-basics./) by [MrRivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/56048/mrrivi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2020-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So basically, I just tried the same PWM control for the servo but on the ESC. Have a look at this gits:

- https://gitlab.com/bradanlane/ros-i2cpwmboard (works fine with my ESC)
- https://github.com/liamondrop/ros-pca9685-board (this one needs WiringPi, couldn't make it work)

My ESC works in a very narrow range (340 on the pwm value means no speed, and 350 means top speed more or less).

I am going to try the proportional control offered in the first git.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [MrRivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/56048/mrrivi/) with karma: 38 on 2020-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0